# How can I find populated indexes in a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array(
  [7] => "foo"
  [10] => "bar"
  [23] => "baz"
)
```

How do I get 7,10,23 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_keys() function

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
foreach($array as $k => $v){
     echo $k."\n";
}
```

The Output will be:

```
7
10
23
```